# Java - String to matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have an input String, which has a size of 9 or 16 or 25... (So always a number which has an integer root.)

I need to create a 2 dimensional matrix from it, which I would like to store in a two dimensional array. I know how to store it in a one dimensional array, but I don't know how to upload the two dimensional array with the elements of the string in a correct way.

It would be something like this:

(Let's assume we have 9 characters now)

```
String Matrix[][] = {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 } };
```

But the order would be this:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
```

I guess I would use two 2 for loop but not sure about it.

Comment: What is the "correct" order that you are trying to get out of it? Also give an example of an input String.

Comment: The `Matrix` variable should be one dimensional

Comment: Can you show us the algorithm that you have so far?

Comment: please post a correct input string

Comment: I think this last edit is not right. The original showed the input as a one dimensional array of strings, not as the desired output. The questions and the answer are no longer related this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good approach would be calculating the square root of the string length: that way you would find out which is the Matrix sizes, and then split up the string in the "rows" or "columns" you want for your matrix.

```
int matrixSize = Math.sqrt(input.length());
for(int i = 0; i<matrixSize; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<matrixSize; j++){
        matrix[i][j] = input[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Swap i and j in the matrix to switch rows for columns.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
string s="123456789";
int n=new int[3][3],p=0;
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        matrix[i][j] =Integer.parseInt(s[p]);
        P++;
    }
```

you may edit dimensions of 2-d array accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
String[] numbers = input.split(",");

int size = (int) Math.sqrt(numbers.length);

String[][] matrix = new String[size][size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        matrix[i][j] = numbers[i * size + j];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets guess your input will be like :

```
 String input="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
```

Then you can do something like :

```
    String[] inputArray=input.replace("\"", "").split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(inputArray[i]);
    }

    int matrixSize=(int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(inputArray.length));

    int i,j;
    int index=0;
    for(i=0;i<matrixSize;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<matrixSize && index<inputArray.length;j++,index++)
            System.out.print(inputArray[index]);
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

It will work for any number of input.